# Почему не хочет загружаться библиотека pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Хотел написать программу, которая сама будет запускать приложение Discord, но при попытке запустить код выдаёт ошибку:
D:\python.exe D:/pythonProject2/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonProject2\main.py", line 1, in 
import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Process finished with exit code 1
Вот моя программа:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('Win')
pyautogui.typewrite('Discord')
pyautogui.PAUSE = 5
pyautogui.keyDown('Enter')
```

Comment: А вы его устанавливали? А в то окружение, из которого скрипт запускаете? На компьютере может быть несколько питонов и в каждом из них может быть по нескольку окружений.

Comment: А как это сделать? Просто я новичок

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ну так то `pip install pyautogui`, но надо в той же среде, от которой вы запускаете питон

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо скачать саму библиотеку. Открой cmd и введи: `pip install pyautogui`
Или же можно нажать в Pycharm’е (если им пользуешься) кнопку Terminal снизу прям и ввести то же самое

Comment: Если помог, нажми галочку, пожалуйста)